# UK patent coverage

Tags: uk

In reference to the patent: [USD738618](https://www.google.com/patents/USD738618)

Does this patent cover the UK?

Answer (score 1):

Thats a US patent. Follow the google link to espacenet and search the patent family tab for european/UK patents.